# netbeans: the replace button is unclickable?

Tags: php, ide, netbeans

i want to find and replace a string in netbeans.

but the edit -> replace button is unclickable.

why is that and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace menu item is enabled only when input focus is in code area.

When there are no open files or input focus is in side tabs (Project, Files, etc.) Replace menu item is not available.

Comment: but i want to find and replace string in all files in my current project. how do i do that?

Comment: `Edit->Replace in projects`... just for the record ;-]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>? That works for me.

It's odd tho, that the one in the edit menu doesn't work... What exactly are you working on when you try this?
What are your specs? OS, Netbeans version, Java version...